# Derivative of a definite integral issue

Tags: integration, derivatives

$g:\mathbb{(0,1]}\to \mathbb{R}$

We have the function $$g\left(x\right)=\int _x^1\left(\frac{\sin\left(t\right)}{t}dt\right)\:$$

Show that the function is strictly decreasing.

So I thought that I'd differentiate the function and prove that the derivative is $\lt0$. I found on-line that that the derivative of this function is:
$$\frac{d}{dx} \int _x^1\left(\frac{\sin(t)}{t}\right) \, dt=-\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$$

Why is that exactly? I thought that $\frac{d}{dx} \int _a^b (f(t)) \, dt = f(t)\text{ from }a\text{ to }b$.

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are just fixed numbers, like $a = 0$ and $b = 1$ for example, and if $f$ is a function of only one variable then $\displaystyle \int \limits_{a}^{b} f(t) \,dt$ is just a number.  So differentiating this with respect to $x$, like differentiating any number (i.e., constant function of one variable) with respect to $x$, you just get the derivative is $0$.  So $\frac{d}{dx}\displaystyle \int \limits_{a}^{b} f(t) \,dt$ is not equal to "$f(t)$ from $a$ to $b$".

Comment: Now, if one of the limits on the integral is not a fixed number, but actually a variable like $x$ (as the upper limit, for example), then we can define the function $F(x)$ to be the value $\displaystyle \int \limits_{a}^{x} f(t)\,dt$.  Since this is now a function of $x$ (i.e., $x$ is the input, and the integral with $x$ as the upper limit is the output), we can differentiate it with respect to $x$.  And by the fundamental theorem of calculus, $F'(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \displaystyle \int \limits_{a}^{x} f(t) \,dt = f(x)$.

Comment: And it would give me $-f(x)$ if $x$ was the lower limit. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Notice that the expression $\int_a^b f(t)\,dt$ has no "$x$" in it.  It doesn't change as $x$ changes.  So its derivative with respect to $x$ is $0$.  And just what $f(t)$ from $a$ to $b$ means might bear elaboration. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: You may just use the Mean Value Theorem for integral to show that $g(x)$ is strictly decreasing in $(0, 1]$.  Using this theorem it is straight forward to show that $x > y $ implies that $g(x) < g(y)$  for $x$ , $y$ in $(0, 1]. But if you are going to use the derivative, please check that you know how to put the function in the form that you may apply the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need of differentiating:

If $0<x<y<1$ then
$$g(x)-g(y)=\int_x^1\frac{\sin t}tdt-\int_y^1\frac{\sin t}tdt=\int_x^y\frac{\sin t}tdt>0$$
since the integrand is positive and $y>x$.

If you still want to differentiate $g$, just write
$$g(x)=\int_0^1\frac{\sin t}tdt-\int_0^x\frac{\sin t}tdt$$
and apply the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Note that you can assume that the integrand is $1$ at $0$ since $\sin t/t\to 1$ when $t\to 0$.

Answer (score 3):

It is because the only dependence on $x$ is in the lower limit of the integral.

Remember that a definite integral, in your case, has the form

$$
g(x)= F(1) - F(x)
$$
with $\frac{d}{dt} F(t) = \frac{\sin t}{t}$, hence the minus sign.

Comment: So far this is the only answer concerned with addressing the user's specific ideas and concerns, rather than just spitting out a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $x,y\in(0,1]$ and $x<y$. Then:

$$ g(x)-g(y) = \int_{x}^{y}\frac{\sin t}{t}\,dt \geq \frac{\sin 1}{1}(y-x), $$
since for any $t\in (0,1]$ we have $\frac{\sin t}{t}\geq \frac{\sin 1}{1}$, because $\sin x$ is a concave function over $(0,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{{\sin (x)}}{x} = 1$ 
and so the function $f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
\frac{{\sin (x)}}{x}{\rm{  , }}x > 0\\
1{\rm{ ,   }}x = 0
\end{array} \right.$ is continuous in $[0,\infty )$.

Now for $x > 0 $, $g(x) = \int_x^1 {\frac{{\sin (t)}}{t}dt}  = \int_x^1 {f(t)dt}  = \int_0^1 {f(t)dt}  - \int_0^x {f(t)} dt$ .

Therefore, for $ x > 0 $, by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus,
$\frac{d}{{dx}}g(x) = \frac{d}{{dx}}\left( {\int_0^1 {f(t)dt}  - \int_0^x {f(t)} dt} \right)$

$ =  - \frac{d}{{dx}}\int_0^x {f(t)} dt =  - f(x) =  - \frac{{\sin (x)}}{x}$ .

Note that when you need to differentiate a function defined by an integral using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, you should check that the integrand function is continuous. Use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus carefully.

For a reference to the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus see [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://037598a680dc5e00a4d1feafd699642badaa7a8c.googledrive.com/host/0B4HffVs7117IbmZ2OTdKSVBZLVk/Mono_bound/mono.htm)